# TS: Disable single equals in if condition

Tags: typescript, react-native

How to disable single equals in an if statement using typescript?
Recently in a codebase that I was debugging, there was and RCTView error on android however that error should be on ios. The issue was a shorthand in a styles file with `(Platform.OS = 'ios' ? "..." : "...");`.

Comment: This sounds like a linting issue: have you looked into tslint and see if it has a rule that disallows this? You can make errors from tslint throw legitimate error exit codes so your pipeline will disallow the case.

Comment: but from my research it seems according to JS they want to allow this method. your suggestion on lint seems a viable option for me https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-cond-assign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment in a conditional is valid Javascript, so this is definitely a task for a linter and not the Typescript compiler. Take a look at [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/). The rule you're looking for is called [no-conditional-assignment](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-conditional-assignment/).

You'd enable it in a `tslint.json` file:

```
{
  "rules": [
    "no-conditional-assignment": true
  ]
}
```